# Does a string literal count as a partial initializer and zero-initialize?

Tags: c, string, initialization, literals

In C, you can *partially initialize* a struct or array, with the result that the members/elements that aren't mentioned in the initializer are zero-initialized. (C99 section 6.7.8.19). For example:-

```
int a[4] = {1, 2};
// a[0] == 1
// a[1] == 2
// a[2] == 0
// a[3] == 0
```

You can also initialize "an array of character type" with a string literal (C99 section 6.7.8.14), and "successive characters ... initialize the elements of the array". For example:-

```
char b[4] = "abc";
// b[0] == 'a'
// b[1] == 'b'
// b[2] == 'c'
// b[3] == '\0'
```

All pretty straightforward. But what happens if you explicitly give the length of the array, but use a literal that's too short to fill the array? Are the remaining characters zero-initialized, or do they have undefined values?

```
char c[4] = "a";
// c[0] == 'a'
// c[1] == '\0'
// c[2] == ?
// c[3] == ?
```

Treating it as a partial initializer would make sense, it would make `char c[4] = "a"` behave exactly like `char c[4] = {'a'}`, and it would have the useful side-effect of letting you zero-initialize a whole character array concisely with `char d[N] = ""`, but it's not at all clear to me that that's what the spec requires.

Comment: Woot. I found a question on SO which makes sense. Dan, you made my day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 char c[4] = "a";
```

All the remaining elements of the array will be set to `0`. That is, not only `c[1]` but also `c[2]` and `c[3]`.

Note that this does not depend on the storage duration of `c`, i. e., even if `c` has automatic storage duration the remaining elements will be set to `0`.

From the C Standard (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.7.8p21) "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, **or fewer characters in a string literal** used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate **shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**"

Comment: Aha, there. That's the clarification I was missing.

Answer (score 8):

From the C99 standard (as already stated by [ouah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119701/ouah)):

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

and:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is
>   not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>     rules.

And `char` is an arithmetic type, so the remaining elements of the array will be initialised to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely everywhere in C language it follows the *all-or-nothing* approach to initialization. If you initialize an aggregate only partially, the rest of that aggregate gets zero-initialized.

One can say that this is excessive and less than optimal with strings, but that's just how it works in C.