# C Array Size Limit

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am using gcc compiler on Linux Redhat. I am surprised why there is 2 characters difference in output of `a[5]` and `a[6]` (Maya and Mayank) though their sizes differ only 1 byte.

```
char a[5]="Mayank";
char b[6]="Mayank";
char c[7]="Mayank";

printf("%s\n",a);
printf("%s\n",b);
printf("%s\n",c);
```

Output:

```
Maya
Mayank
Mayank
```

Comment: Does it compile http://codepad.org/Wh4a56RA

Answer (score 8):

The first two `printf` calls have [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since neither `a` nor `b` include a terminating NUL character (`c` does, so the last `printf()` would be fine on its own).

Comment: Only first is Undefined `char b[6]="Mayank";`  is valid in C (but bot in C++), that is same as `char b[6] = {'M', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'n', 'k'}`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Is it?  There are seven characters in `"Mayank"`, counting the nul.  The array is too small to hold them all.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: How so? Where does the NUL required by `%s` come from?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan your statement is not true.

Comment: this is special case in C but not valid in C++. @IvayloStrandjev try with `gcc -Wall -pedantic` you willget waring for first but not for second

Comment: @NPE I had same confusion some days back and I had a conversation with [Keith Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson). You can [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790127/what-is-meant-by-char-temp3/17790207#comment27226774_17790207)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: You are missing the point, which is that **the `%s` in `printf()` requires a NUL terminator.** If there's no NUL, the behaviour of `printf()` is undefined.

Comment: I don't give a damn what GCC says.  The nul *must* be there, or you end up with UB when you try to treat the char array as a string (as `printf` does).  And there's not enough room for it in a 6-element array, so it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a[5]="Mayank";
```

You are filling an array of 5 elements with a string that contains 7 elements (7 charachters).

`"Mayank"` contains 6 charachters + a null charachter (`'\0'`) at the end of the string

So this is **undefined behaviour**. So you will get a random output.

Same thing for

```
char b[6]="Mayank";
```

And it's OK for the

```
char b[7]="Mayank";
```

Comment: Not true. This is not the problem.