# C char array initialization: what happens if there are less characters in the string literal than the array size?

Tags: c, arrays, char, initialization, buffer

I'm not sure what will be in the char array after initialization in the following ways.

1.`char buf[10] = "";`
2. `char buf[10] = " ";`
3. `char buf[10] = "a";`

For case 2, I think `buf[0]` should be `' '`, `buf[1]` should be `'\0'`, and from `buf[2]` to `buf[9]` will be random content. For case 3, I think `buf[0]` should be `'a'`, `buf[1]` should be '\0', and from `buf[2]` to `buf[9]` will be random content.

Is that correct?

And for the case 1, what will be in the `buf`? `buf[0] == '\0'` and from `buf[1]` to `buf[9]` will be random content?

Comment: Well, my compiler does not accept your (corrected) code: "array type 'char [10]' is not assignable".

Comment: @MartinR now it will work...

Comment: @lkkeepmoving: `char buf[10]; buf = "a";` does *not* compile. - Please try it first, and then copy/paste your *actual* code into the question. That saves a lot of work for you and for all readers of your question.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry for that. I thought I can assign the buf[] latter but it seems no. Now the code runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a string literal count as a partial initializer and zero-initialize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780809/does-a-string-literal-count-as-a-partial-initializer-and-zero-initialize)

Comment: That older question has answers drawing from standards and also talks about aggregate initializer as well

Comment: I don't think the other question covers all question cases here. Also, this question is more search-friendly and clear, which results in more views on this question. Thanks!

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'll delete all my comments since they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

1. The first declaration:

   ```
    char buf[10] = "";
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
    char buf[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   ```
2. The second declaration:

   ```
    char buf[10] = " ";
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
    char buf[10] = {' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   ```
3. The third declaration:

   ```
    char buf[10] = "a";
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
    char buf[10] = {'a', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   ```

As you can see, no random content: if there are fewer initializers, the remaining of the array is initialized with `0`. This the case even if the array is declared inside a function.

Comment: For the sake of the person asking the question, it's worth pointing out that the C standard requires any partially-complete array initialisation to be padded with zero for the remaining elements (by the compiler).  This goes for all data types, not just `char`.

Comment: @ouah why there is no '\0' at the end of buf[]?

Comment: @lkkeepmoving `0` and `'\0` have the same value.

Comment: And why I can not do  'char buf[10]; buf = "a"' ?

Comment: @lkkeepmoving because C requires you to initialize at declaration time. You then cannot assign a value to an array.

Comment: @lkkeepmoving Initialization and assignment are two different beasts, thus C lets you provide a string as an initializer for a char array, but forbids array assignments (as ouah said).

Comment: @StevenPenny I rolled back your edit, it's correct but I don't think it adds anything more.

Comment: @ouah, What happens then when you have more elements than space? E.g. `char buff[3] = "abcdefghijkl";` ? Is this valid and identical to char `buff[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}`?

Comment: @Pacerier it is invalid as per c99, 6.7.8p1.

Comment: @ouah, Do you mean that `char buff[3] = "abcdefghijkl";` wouldn't compile? (I'm not a C coder.) Then why will [`char p3[5] = "String";`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732325/how-to-declare-strings-in-c/8732358#comment-10874556) compile?

Comment: @Pacerier `char buff[3] = "abcdefghijkl";` is invalid. `char p3[5] = "String";` is also invalid. `char p[6] = "String";` is valid and   is the same as `char p[6] = {'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'};`.

Comment: @Pacerier for the terminology, there is a constraint violation in the two invalid examples, which means an compiler is required to issue a diagnostic and may refuse to compile the program.

Comment: what about  char buf[] = {}?

Comment: @LeiYang `char buf[] = {}` is invalid in C as empty initializers are not allowed. GNU C allows it and it declares an array of size `0`.

Comment: If you have a constant MAX = 5000, I will not put 0x500 in my code... is crazy solution!!!! if you want set a value in a function use "strcpy" please...

Comment: @delive What do you mean, and what relevance did it have to this answer?

Comment: `This is not how you initialize an array` what do you mean

Answer (score 44):

1. These are equivalent

   ```
   char buf[10] = "";
   char buf[10] = {0};
   char buf[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   ```
2. These are equivalent

   ```
   char buf[10] = " ";
   char buf[10] = {' '};
   char buf[10] = {' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   ```
3. These are equivalent

   ```
   char buf[10] = "a";
   char buf[10] = {'a'};
   char buf[10] = {'a', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   ```

Answer (score 31):

*Edit: OP (or an editor) silently changed some of the single quotes in the original question to double quotes at some point after I provided this answer.*

Your code will result in compiler errors. Your first code fragment:

```
char buf[10] ; buf = ''
```

is doubly illegal. First, in C, there is no such thing as an empty `char`. You can use double quotes to designate an empty string, as with:

```
char* buf = "";
```

That will give you a pointer to a `NUL` string, i.e., a single-character string with only the `NUL` character in it. But you cannot use single quotes with nothing inside them--that is undefined. If you need to designate the `NUL` character, you have to specify it:

```
char buf = '\0';
```

The backslash is necessary to disambiguate from character `'0'`.

```
char buf = 0;
```

accomplishes the same thing, but the former is a tad less ambiguous to read, I think.

Secondly, you cannot initialize arrays after they have been defined.

```
char buf[10];
```

declares and defines the array. The array identifier `buf` is now an address in memory, and you cannot change where `buf` points through assignment. So

```
buf =     // anything on RHS
```

is illegal. Your second and third code fragments are illegal for this reason.

To initialize an array, you have to do it at the time of definition:

```
char buf [10] = ' ';
```

will give you a 10-character array with the first char being the space `'\040'` and the rest being `NUL`, i.e., `'\0'`. When an array is declared and defined with an initializer, the array elements (if any) past the ones with specified initial values are automatically padded with `0`. There will not be any "random content".

If you declare and define the array but don't initialize it, as in the following:

```
char buf [10];
```

you will have random content in all the elements.

Comment: "To initialize an array, you have to do it at the time of definition..." This, and the following line makes this better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

The relevant part of C11 standard draft n1570 6.7.9 initialization says:

> **14**   An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string
>        literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
>        terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>        elements of the array.

and

> **21**   **If there are** fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>        of an aggregate, or **fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>        size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>        initialized implicitly the same as objects that have *static storage duration.***

Thus, the '\0' is appended, **if there is enough space**, and the remaining characters are initialized with the value that a `static char c;` would be initialized within a function.

Finally,

> **10**   If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>        indeterminate. If an object that has **static** or thread storage duration is not initialized
>        explicitly, then:
>
> [--]
>
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> [--]

Thus, `char` being an arithmetic type the remainder of the array is also guaranteed to be initialized with zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly enough, it is possible to initialize arrays in any way at any time in the program, provided they are members of a `struct` or `union`.

**Example program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct ccont
{
  char array[32];
};

struct icont
{
  int array[32];
};

int main()
{
  int  cnt;
  char carray[32] = { 'A', 66, 6*11+1 };    // 'A', 'B', 'C', '\0', '\0', ...
  int  iarray[32] = { 67, 42, 25 };

  struct ccont cc = { 0 };
  struct icont ic = { 0 };

  /*  these don't work
  carray = { [0]=1 };           // expected expression before '{' token
  carray = { [0 ... 31]=1 };    // (likewise)
  carray = (char[32]){ [0]=3 }; // incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[32]' from type 'char *'
  iarray = (int[32]){ 1 };      // (likewise, but s/char/int/g)
  */

  // but these perfectly work...
  cc = (struct ccont){ .array='a' };        // 'a', '\0', '\0', '\0', ...
  // the following is a gcc extension, 
  cc = (struct ccont){ .array={ [0 ... 2]='a' } };  // 'a', 'a', 'a', '\0', '\0', ...
  ic = (struct icont){ .array={ 42,67 } };      // 42, 67, 0, 0, 0, ...
  // index ranges can overlap, the latter override the former
  // (no compiler warning with -Wall -Wextra)
  ic = (struct icont){ .array={ [0 ... 1]=42, [1 ... 2]=67 } }; // 42, 67, 67, 0, 0, ...

  for (cnt=0; cnt<5; cnt++)
    printf("%2d %c %2d %c\n",iarray[cnt], carray[cnt],ic.array[cnt],cc.array[cnt]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I commonly initialize an array to ""
in that case I don't need worry about the null end of the string.

```
main() {
    void something(char[]);
    char s[100] = "";

    something(s);
    printf("%s", s);
}

void something(char s[]) {
    // ... do something, pass the output to s
    // no need to add s[i] = '\0'; because all unused slot is already set to '\0'
}
```

Comment: You should not really make use of the *implicit int* rule. You should specify a type for `main()` (and you should also use `void`, i.e., `int main(void) { ... }`. C99 got rid of this rule, so this code will not compile for C99 and later. The other thing to note here is that *starting* with C99, if you omit `return` in main, there is an automatic `return 0;` placed/implied before the `}` at main's end. You are making use of implicit int rule which only works before C99, yet you are making use of the implicit `return` that only works with C99 and *later*; these two are obviously contradictory.