# How to use default values in a char array?

Tags: arrays, c, syntax-error, default-value

I have the easiest question possible: how to initialise a value in C?
My variable is of the type char[20] and it is declared somewhere outside of my unit. It is impossible to change the type.

Now I would like to give it a default value, let's say all empty characters (or spaces, whatever), but this is not working at all.
I have already tried :

**Method 1.**

```
host = "";
```

> => cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char [20]'

**Method 2.**

```
host = "                   ";
```

> => cannot convert from 'const char [20]' to 'char [20]

**Method 3.**

```
host = '                   ';
```

> => cannot convert from 'int' to 'char [20]

**Method 4.**

```
host = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", };
```

> => syntax error : '{'

...

I am getting desperate here: how and why have the inventors of C made it so difficult to simply declare a value to a variable :-( ?

Comment: Have you even tried to google "*c char array initialize*"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688971/c-char-array-initialization

Comment: How have you declared `host` ?

Comment: Don't you use single quotes for chars ?Also if you want to populate the array you have to do so when the variable is declared. Otherwise you have to change each individual element.

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
memset(&host, 0, sizeof(host));
```

will fill it with zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you know, the meaning of `initialize`? Usually, it's performed at defining time only.
2. `declared somewhere outside of my unit`, or do you mean `defined`?

If `host` is really `declared` elsewhere, while `defining` it, you may use

```
char host[20] = {0};   //to fill with 0
```

or

```
char host[20] = { [0 ... 19] = 5 };  //to fill with 5 , supported on gcc
```

At any later point, if you want to `re-initialize` to some value, `memset()` is the way to go.

Check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

Comment: `char host[20] = { 5, };` will put `5` on the first position of the array and will complete the rest of it with zeroes.

Comment: @axiac my bad !! donno how I missed that. sorry and thank you for drawing attention. Updated with intended code.

Comment: Nice trick, but if `host` is a string (not an array of small ints) I suggest `[0 ... 18] = '5';` followed by `host[19] = '\0'`

Comment: @AlterMann thank you sir for broadening the scope of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
host = "";
```

Will work only if the it is char* and not char[20] (if you are doing a function just make the parameter char*).
The

```
host = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", };
```

It's ok but, first use

```
{'character', 'character','character'...
```

(substitute the character with any character of ASCII for example `\0`).

Secondly (that is the main problem here) you have a space, where it shouldn't be (in the end, so delete this) .

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you have declared the host variable as an integer variable. If you have declared that as char variable,

```
host = "";
host = "     ";
```

These two are possible. Because it will take the characters for corresponding
position.

`host = '     ';` It is not possible because in single quotes we have to give the character only. In this you  have to mention the array position otherwise it will throw the error.
host[0]=' ';

```
host = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", };
```

It is not possible because in this it will take the corresponding characters not a string.