# Concatenate all input strings [ C programming ]

Tags: c, string, input, concatenation

I am new to c programming and would like to write a program which has the following requirement:

Input: The number of inputs n, then n input chars , for example, 3 welcome to hku

Output concatenated chars, for example, welcomehku

However, I discovered a problem that when I submit the codes as following to the c autochecking platform, the output is ~~~~welcometohku instead of welcometohku.

Would anyone like to give help on the issue? Thank you very much to all of you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int num;  /* array with 50 elements */
    int i = 0;
    char iarray1[100];
    /* read array */
    scanf("%d", &num);

    char iarray[num][100];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        scanf("%s", iarray[i]);
    }   

    /* print array elements in reverse order */
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        strcat(iarray1,iarray[i]);
    }

    //display the concatenated string
    printf("%s",iarray1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: importance of array initialization  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38201811/3698648

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `iarray1`

Try

```
char iarray1[100] = {0};
```

The reason is that an uninitialized `iarray1` may contain any value. So when you do the first `strcat` it may happen the string you want to concatenate is appended to some gargabe value.

Comment: May I ask why I need to initialize? I thought declaration of array with its size is enough when using c++?