# ISO C95 array initialization guarantee

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer, string-literals, aggregate-initialization

I am trying to find documentation either confirming or contradicting the statement that

```
char test[5]="";
```

results in a buffer initialized to all null characters identical to

```
memset(test,'\0',sizeof(test));
```

but have not been able to find (or understand / decipher) anything. I am specifically looking for details in the old specification, C99 reference will work too. 
Thank you

Comment: Don't know what C95 is, but yes, it is equivalent. The documentation is to follow...

Comment: Do you mean C99?

Comment: Here it is http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21

Comment: `char test[5] = {0};` should also work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Post the relevant quote as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I am sure it is a duplicate, looking for one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C char array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688971/c-char-array-initialization)

Comment: @EugeneSh. your text is from C11 but this question is about C95

Comment: @M.M I am not aware of C95 standard revision, so assuming it is a typo/mistake.... actually found it, it is an *extension* of C90. I don't have a link to a free copy/draft of it. Still not sure the OP is meaning it. FWIW C89 has a very similar wording in http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.7

Comment: I am looking for the (very) old specification, I understand c11 defines it as described.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The original ISO C standard was issued in 1990. An amendment was published in 1995; it added digraphs, `__STDC_VERSION__`, and if I recall correctly `<iso646.h>`. Most compilers don't bother to distinguish between C90 and C95. I don't believe there have been any changes in the 1995 amendment or in the 1999, 2011, or any later editions that would affect the answer to the OP's question. On the other hand, C90/C95 may have made some assumptions that later editions made explicitl. (I have copies of the 1990 standard and 1995 amendment which I can check later.)

Comment: I've edited "NULL characters" to "null characters". `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant, and should not (at least in the context of C) be used to refer to the character value.

Comment: a c99 reference would do too, thank you

Comment: @PhilC C99 is pretty much the same as C11 for this matter: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.8p21

Comment: `gcc -std=iso9899:199409` tells gcc to use C94/C95, and sets `__STDC_VERSION__` to `199409L`. BTW, I updated the title to refer to ISO, which has issued all the C standard editions since 1990 (ANSI then adopts the ISO standard).

Comment: I wrote: "*I don't believe there have been any changes in the 1995 amendment or in the 1999, 2011, or any later editions that would affect the answer to the OP's question.*". Based on further discussion, it's quite likely I was mistaken, and that the C90 standard is at least less explicit on this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is not a complete answer to your question but serves to clear up misinformation in other answers*.

In ANSI C89 the relevant Standard text was (section 3.5.7):

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.
>
> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the members of the array.

It only specifies the initialization for array elements corresponding to the string literal. So the trailing array elements are not explicitly initialized and thus have indeterminate value.

There was also a paragraph:

> If there are fewer initializers **in a list** than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

but that does not apply since we are not initializing from a list ("list" means a brace-enclosed list, not a string literal).

---

In C90 (which I'm not sure if I can legally link to), the sections were renumbered so that the section containing these paragraphs became 6.5.7. The wording of the latter paragraph was also changed:

> If there are fewer initializers in a **brace-enclosed** list than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

---

In C90 TC1 ([HTML](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/tc1.htm), [PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n423.pdf)), the above is unaltered.

However, in [Defect Report 60](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_060.html), the crucial question was asked:

> When an array of char (or wchar_t) is initialized with a string literal that contains fewer characters than the array, are the remaining elements of the array initialized?
>
> Subclause 6.5.7 Initialization, page 72, only says (emphasis mine):
>
> *If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.*
>
> **Correction**
>
> In subclause 6.5.7, page 72, the penultimate paragraph of Semantics (before Examples), add after the comma:
>
> *or fewer characters in a string literal or wide string literal used to initialize an array of known size, and elements of character or wchar_t type*

It appears that the zero initialisation in the suggested fix must indeed have been the standard-writers intention, since in [C90 TC2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/tc2.htm), we see that same crucial change made:

> *Page 72*
>
> **In subclause 6.5.7, page 72, the penultimate paragraph of Semantics (before Examples), add after the comma:**
>
> or fewer characters in a string literal or wide string literal used to initialize an array of known size, and elements of character or wchar_t type

giving us:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are members of an aggregate, **or fewer characters in a string literal or wide string literal used to initialize an array of known size, and elements of character or wchar_t type** the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Note that TC1 is dated 1994, although it was published in 1995. TC2 is dated 1996. Perplexingly, DR60 is dated July 16 1993, and hence predates TC1. Perhaps work on TC1 was at too advanced a stage by that point to deal with new defect reports and a backlog had accumulated? In any case, TC2 was mostly just a set of corrections in response to defect reports, suggesting that the change was first seen there and not in C95, and that the zero-initialisation of characters after the null terminator was what the C89 standard writers had intended.

---

In ISO C99 (the original version, without the technical corrigenda), that paragraph was now renumbered to 6.7.8/21 and had changed again. The mentions of *"wide string literal"* and *"elements of character or wchar_t type"* were removed:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, **or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array**, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Meaning the trailing array elements are initialized to null bytes .

(**Note: The original C99 may be copyrighted material, so I can't post a link to it in the above. That is what it says, though. [Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n843.htm) is a link to the last freely available working draft. There were two more drafts after that, but the WG14 website has taken them down. Nevertheless, that wording is in the N843 working draft, and is still present in the later C99 incorporating TC3.**)

---

I have been unable to find any free copies of C95 (ISO/IEC 9899:1990/AMD1:1995). So I cannot answer as to exactly which point between C89 and C99 the "wide string literal" and "wchar_t" changes were made.  Also, the subject is not mentioned in the C99 Rationale document.

Of course it is possible that the C99 behaviour was the intent of the C89 authors and the missing text was an oversight, but in the absence of any sort of documentation to that effect we can't draw any conclusion, and there may be compilers from that time that do not initialize the trailing elements.

Hopefully someone else out there who has those documents (or feels inclined to buy them from the ISO store!) can provide an accurate answer.

Comment: I'll check my copies later. It's possible that the authors of the C90 standard implicitly assumed that the array would be zero-filled, and that later editions just made that assumption explicit.

Comment: @KeithThompson OK, that would be great.  Surely we can't know their intent unless they documented it though, so we have to take the letter of the text as the specified behaviour (and more importantly, compiler vendors may do the same).  I do recall having discussed this issue before in the c.l.c days , maybe even before C99 was published , perhaps due to people observing compilers not initializing the trailing elements. Possibly there is something relevant in those archives

Comment: @KeithThompson I made the answer community-wiki so feel free to edit once you have access to your documents

Comment: Thanks. It seemed easier to post my own answer.

Comment: About C95 - I can't find the full version online, but http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/na1.html has what looks like an official summary of it posted, and it doesn't mention array initialization using string literals.

Comment: Surprisingly, the summary's author (Clive Feather) doesn't host it at his own website, although he has written other content relating to the C language and standard which he hosts there.

Comment: The text in section 3.5.7 of C89 is in section 6.5.7 of C90, so there's some section renumbering. There is also a change to the key paragraph, which now reads *"If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are members of an aggregate,
the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."*

Comment: Edited the above into the answer. Also added material from C90 TC2, which contains most of the relevant change. There are still changes between C90 TC2 and C99 TC2 that haven't been sourced, though.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica I think it is a bad idea to link to copyrighted material; as if a DMCA strike is issued then the result will be that this entire thread is permanently removed . Perhaps you could edit to summarize without the link

Comment: @M.M I think this is the pre-corrigenda C99 you're referring to? I've removed the link. If it's something else, please let me know ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

#### Quick summary

C99 and later guarantees that the remaining characters are initialized to zero. C89/C90/C95 does not make this guarantee and does not specify the values of the remaining characters. This was likely an unintentional oversight, and I speculate that most or all pre-C99 compilers would have zero-initialized the remaining characters anyway. If you're using a conforming C99 or later compiler, zero-initialization is guaranteed.

#### The gory details

```
char test[5]="";
```

Due to a defect in the C89/C90 standard, this was only guaranteed to initialize `test[0]` to `'\0'`. The other elements of `test` were left unspecified.

The C95 amendment did not address this.

The C99 standard corrected the defect, requiring `test` to be initialized to all zeros.

Another example:

```
char foo[5] = "foo";
```

In C89/C90,C95, the language guaranteed `foo[0]=='f', foo[1]=='o', foo[2]=='o', foo[3]=='\0'`, but said nothing about the value of `foo[4]`. In C99 and later, it's guaranteed to be initialized as if you had written:

```
char foo[5] = { 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0' };
```

which, in all editions of the C standard, guarantees `foo[4]=='\0'`.

#### Citations

The 1989 ANSI C standard and the 1990 ISO C standard are equivalent, differing only in non-normative introductory material and a renumbering of sections. The 1995 amendment updated the standard but did not affect array initialization.

The 1990 ISO C standard, section 6.5.7, says:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

and later in the same section:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

It specified that trailing members are initialized to zero for a brace-enclosed list, but does not make the same statement for a string literal initializer. (I speculate that this was an unintentional oversight, and that most compilers would have zero-filled the remaining elements anyway since they already had to do so in some cases.)

Each edition of the C standard has a collection of defect reports associated with it:

- [C90 Defect Reports](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr.htm)
- [C99 Defect Reports](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary-c99.htm)
- [C11 Defect Reports](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm)

[C90 Defect Report #060](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_060.html), submitted in 1993 by P.J. Plauger and/or Larry Jones, raised this issue:

> When an array of **`char`** (or **`wchar_t`**) is initialized with a
>   string literal that contains fewer characters than the array, are the
>   remaining elements of the array initialized?
>   Subclause 6.5.7
>   **Initialization**, page 72, only says (emphasis mine):
>
> > If there are fewer initializers in a *brace-enclosed* list than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

The response to this defect report resulted in the revised wording in the C99 standard, section 6.7.8 paragraph 21 (emphasis added):

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, *or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array*, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;
>
> ...

and

> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

This means that in this declaration

```
char test[5] = "";
```

all five elements of the array are zero initialized. The first element is initialized explicitly by the terminating zero of the string literal and all other are initialized implicitly the same way as objects with the static storage duration.

At least it is valid starting from the C99 Standard.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows different ways of initialization of character arrays with zeroes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 5 };

    char s1[N] = "";
    char s2[N] = { "" };
    char s3[N] = { 0 };
    char s4[N] = { [0] = 0 };
    char s5[N] = { [N-1] = 0 };

    char * s[] = { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d", s[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

Comment: which version of C Standard do you quote?

Comment: @M.M I quote the C11 Standard. But I am sure the same valid for C89 Standard.

Comment: The C89 standard does not contain the provision "or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array"

Comment: @M.M Isn't it just a clarification but not an actual addition?

Comment: @EugeneSh. not sure what you mean; this is normative text we are talking about

Comment: @M.M I have no under hand the Standard but as I remember there should be a similar statement.

Answer (score 0):

From a code clarity point of view, if the purpose of the array is to hold strings, then

```
char test[5] = "";
```

initializes the array with a zero-length string, and the rest of the bytes shouldn't matter. If they do matter, then the array isn't really a string, and you should use

```
char test[5] = {0};
```

to clarify that.

Comment: These two are exactly the same.

Comment: @EugeneSh. they are the same in C11, but were different in C89

Comment: That is what I was looking for, trying to identify exactly how the specifications differed, but have yet been unable to find documentation. Thank you

Comment: @EugeneSh., they are exactly the same *to the compiler*. But code doesn't just communicate to a compiler--it also communicates to human beings.