# Why does splint suggest that { 0 } doesn't really initialize all elements to zero in C: Initializer does not define all elements of a declared array

Tags: c, c89, splint

In this piece of code (the whole file contains only one line):

```c
char buffer[256] = { 0 };
```

Checked with Splint, I got the following hint:

```
foo.c(1,20): Initializer block for buffer has 1 element, but declared as char
                [256]: 0
  Initializer does not define all elements of a declared array. (Use
  -initallelements to inhibit warning)
```

**Initializer does not define all elements of a declared array.** This is puzzling: I read some SO answers, but all of them claims that `{ 0 }` does initialize all elements to zero.

---

Splint version:

```
Splint 3.1.1 --- 12 April 2003

Maintainer: splint-bug@splint.org
Compiled using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0
```

Downloaded from [Splint.org](http://splint.org/win32.html).

Comment: Not sure if there is something special about C89 but for the latest C standard, the answer is yes - it initializes all elements.

Comment: splint is trying (and failing in this particular instance) to be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does zero all the elements. The general rule is that if you provide less initializers than there are elements, the remaining elements are zeroed. (So e.g. `char buffer[256] = {1};` will set only the first element to `1`, and the rest to `0`.)

The warning doesn't say that remaining elements are uninitialized, it says **you** didn't provide initializers for them. This warning doesn't make sense in this specific case (`= {0}` is a common pattern to zero an array), but in general it could be useful (e.g. it would warn about `int arr[4] = {1,2,3};`).

Comment: Thank you, you made it all clear. I misunderstood what Splint is trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

For char array like that, the most common (and safe) way seems to be:

```
char buffer[256] = "";
```

It may be initialised using empty {} just like other struct types:

```
char buffer[256] = {};  // not working in C, only work for C++
```

Using `{0}` seems to be more C++ way to initialise struct type.

Comment: `= {}` doesn't work in C, it's a C++ thing. Otherwise we wouldn't be using `= {0}`.

Comment: Initializing with `""` is great! I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Ayoama initializing with `""` doesn't set to zero all the array but just the first element: that is the nul char terminating an empty string.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni are you sure? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688971/c-char-array-initialization

Comment: @artm I used to be.. :) Probably I had to deal too much with c89 stuff. I'll verify it.

Comment: `={0}` is common enough in C

Comment: Not sure I fully understand this answer. 1) Why C++ code? As far as I can see the Q has never had a C++ tag. 2) Why should it be more "safe"? 3) Do you a reference for the "most common" claim? To me it would depend on the use of `buffer`. If `buffer` was to be used as a string, I would initialize with `""` but if `buffer` was be used for other things I would initialize with `{0}`.