# how to initialize a matrix in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, declaration, array-initialization

I need to initialize a `h x h` matrix in C with spaces.

How to properly do it without cycles?

```
int h = 8;
char arr[h][h] = {{' '}}; // does not work....
```

Comment: You can't have partial initializer here. Will have to provide a full initializer. Partial initializers are assuming zeros for the parts which are missing.

Comment: This is a variable-length-array (VLA), where the dimension is variable. You can't initialize VLAs. If you make `h` constant (e.g. an enumerated value), you can initialize it.

Comment: @MOehm, if constant, how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `memset()`?

Comment: Or [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18688992/102937)

Comment: `enum { h = 8 };` or `#define DIM 8`, for example.

Comment: Won't work with the vla, but this works in gcc and clang: `char arr[8][8] = { [0 ... 7] = {[0 ... 7] = ' '}};`.  Pretty sure it is a non-standard extension in both compilers.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These declarations

```
int h = 8;
char arr[h][h] = {{' '}};
```

declare a variable length array. Variable length arrays may be declared only within functions (as for example within main) because they shall have automatic storage duration and may not be initialized in declarations.

So you can write for example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int main( void )
{
    int h = 8;
    char arr[h][h];

    memset( arr, ' ', h * h );
    //...
}
```

That is you can apply the standard function `memset` that sets all characters of the array with the space character `' '`.

Even if you have a non-variable length array nevertheless to initialize its all elements with the space character it is better to use the function `memset`.

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int main( void )
{
    enum { h = 8 };
    char arr[h][h];

    memset( arr, ' ', h * h );
    //...
}
```

Comment: `memset(arr, ' ', sizeof arr)` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

From [GNU site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write ‘[first ...
> last] = value’. This is a GNU extension

You can use designated initializers. But this type of initialization works, only for `constant number of rows and columns`.

```
char arr[8][8] = { { [0 ... 7] = ' '}, { [0 ... 7] = ' '}, { [0 ... 7] = ' '}, { [0 ... 7] = ' '}, { [0 ... 7] = ' '}, { [0 ... 7] = ' '}, { [0 ... 7] = ' '}, { [0 ... 7] = ' '}  };
```

Comment: This is not a standard C feature. Moreover it uses the magic number 7.

Comment: Please visit this site :https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: Where do you have found such initializer  [0 ... 7] = ' ' in the question at link?

Comment: Have you tested this?  Designated initializers or not, you're still trying to initialize a VLA...

Comment: "To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write ‘[first ... last] = value’. This is a GNU extension"  From that link

Comment: Yes, designated initializers are fine... but they don't get around the fact that you're initializing a VLA.  If you made the dimensions constants, it would work.. but as is?

Comment: @Dmitri  OP mentioned that `h = 8` .  OP did not mention about Variable lenght array.

Comment: It's a VLA because the dimensions are specified with a variable rather than a constant.

Comment: What you really want to do is: `{ [0 ... h] = ' '},` but I'm not sure you can because `h` is `int h = 8;`. Even if we do: `#define h 8`, there's an issue. If we _change_ the value (e.g. to `9`), the sequence breaks [not enough repetition]. Designated initializers are fine [I use them a lot], but doing `memset` or some `for` loops is actually a better solution for this given problem.

Comment: @CraigEstey Ok. I understoof now. Thank you!

Comment: @Dmitri  Thank you for the discussion. I understood.