# Variable not updating even with volatile, no threads

Tags: c, printf, volatile

I have the following `printf` statement which prints the output of a function:

```
printf("\nStart-Time %s,End-Time %s",
       get_time(myfields[i].start_mn),
       get_time(myfields[i].end_mn));
```

In the statement the `get_time` function is called twice with different arguments.  However, even though the function returns different strings on the two calls, the `printf` only prints the return from the first call for the second call also.  I have tried the `volatile` keyword for the function return variable and the function itself, but the output is still the same.
But if I split the `printf` statement into two `printf` stataments to print the values separately,they are printing different values which is expected.

So can anyone point to me what is happening here and what is the correct way of doing this?

---

[Update from comment:]

`get_time` is returning a global `char` array.  `char *get_time(int tval)` converts time in minutes to hour.

Comment: I bet you're returning a local character array (bad idea), but it's impossible to know until you post the actual source code.

Comment: Perhaps your get_time function is not [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)). Can we see its code ? Where does your get_time() store the string it returns ?

Comment: get_time is returning a global char array.                                                       char *get_time(int tval)//Converts time in minutes to hour

Comment: @TinTop, so you pass `printf` the same char array twice, and expect the values printed to be different?

Comment: Then that's your problem -- both calls return the same pointer to the same array, which will contain whatever the call that happened second put there (overwriting the result of the first call).  Which call is first is implementation defined.

Comment: i pass it an integer value and it converts it to string and return an array which is declared globally.

Comment: @TinTop, that's not what you pass `printf`

Comment: thanks Chris,I understand it now.Yeah it was my problem.I should have thought about it.

Comment: Downvoted because you don't show us relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

> So can anyone point to me what is happening here and what is the correct way of doing this?

Each call to `get_time()` returns the same address to the same buffer, which are then passed to `printf()`, which finds in this very one buffer what had been put in last, with "last" in terms of "last in time".

To get around this create temporary buffers to pass to `printf()`:

```
char * p1 = strdup(get_time(...));
char * p2 = strdup(get_time(...));

printf("\nStart-Time %s,End-Time %s", p1, p2);

/* Free the temporary buffers. */
free(p1);
free(p2);
```

A more simple approach would do if you know the maximum size of what `get_time()` returns in advance:

```
#define GET_TIME_LEN_MAX 32

...

char b1[GET_TIME_LEN_MAX];
char b2[GET_TIME_LEN_MAX];

strcpy(b1, get_time(...));
strcpy(b2, get_time(...));

printf("\nStart-Time %s,End-Time %s", b1, b2);
```

The safe version of the latter example:

```
#define GET_TIME_LEN_MAX 32

...

/* Define buffers and initialise them to ALL zeros. */
char b1[GET_TIME_LEN_MAX] = "";
char b2[GET_TIME_LEN_MAX] = "";

strncpy(b1, get_time(...), GET_TIME_LEN_MAX - 1);
strncpy(b2, get_time(...), GET_TIME_LEN_MAX - 1);

printf("\nStart-Time %s,End-Time %s", b1, b2);
```

---

As [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) isn't Standard C, for completeness find a home grown implementation below:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */
#include <string.h> /* for strcpy() */


char * strdup(const char * s)
{
  char * p = NULL;

  if (NULL != s)
  {
    p = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (NULL != p)
    {
      strcpy(p, s);
    }
  }

  return p;
}
```

Comment: "Last" is a bit misleading in this context.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Err, why?

Comment: thanks alk.I ought to change my code like you pointed out.Currently I am using two printfs.

Comment: @TinTop: "*.. two printf ...*" which probably is the simplest solution! :-)

Comment: To the uninitiated "last" could mean "The last invocation of get_time() as written". It's not a flaw with the answer itself, just that this point could be misconstrued

Comment: @StoryTeller: Ahok, fixed. Thx!

Comment: Did you mean `char* p1 = strdup(get_time(...))`, and `char* p2`?

Comment: Disagree that `char b1[GET_TIME_LEN_MAX] = ""; strncpy(b1, ..., GET_TIME_LEN_MAX - 1); printf("%s%s", b1);` is safe as there is no guarantee that `b1` is null character terminated before printing.  Perhaps you meant `char b1[GET_TIME_LEN_MAX] = {0};`.  Recommend `char b1[GET_TIME_LEN_MAX] = "";
strncat(b1, get_time(...), GET_TIME_LEN_MAX);`  `strncpy()` is tricky to use.

Comment: @E.Moffat: Yes, I did. Fixed now. Thx!

Comment: @chux: Doing `char s[42] = ""` zeros out the whole array and in fact is equivalent to `... = {0}`. Please see this answer citing the Standard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11780856/694576

Comment: Note that `strdup()` isn't a standard C function, and those platforms that provide it normally require the user to release the memory so acquired (usually with `free()`, but check the man page for your system).

Comment: Agree that your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004089/variable-not-updating-even-with-volatile-no-threads/34004371?noredirect=1#comment55788026_34004371) negates the premise of my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004089/variable-not-updating-even-with-volatile-no-threads/34004371?noredirect=1#comment55788026_34004371).  LSNED.