# Printing a list which has elements other lists (same struct) recursively

Tags: c

This is how i recursively print a list:

```
if (mylist_ptr == NULL) {
        return ;
    }


    printf("%s: ", mylist_ptr->str);
    report(mylist_ptr->next);


    return ;
```

Now i want to print a list which has elements other lists,same way(recursively).
This is how my list looks like.

```
       |-->    `Link0`      `Link1`      `Link2`      `Link3`
       |     list1        list2        list3        list4
       |    next         next         next          NULL
```

`newlist`-|

and each sublist after the last link ,and the final link is linked with `NULL`.Also the structs:

```
struct link {
    char value[20] ;
    struct link* next ;    
} ;


typedef struct link Link;
typedef Link * List;


struct lstlst{
    List list;
    struct lstlst*next;
} ; 
typedef struct lstlst Listoflists;
```

I wrote 5 more lines but they got lost after i refreshed cause i deleted my post so im going to be a little bit more short if thats ok.

Comment: This looks like some random pieces of code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thats why i add explenation .I dont think posting 600 lines of code changes anything.

Comment: 600 lines of code and an [mcve] are two totally different things. We do not want to see 600 lines, you are right. But we still want an MCVE.

Comment: do i delete and repost later?

Comment: Maybe that would be the best bet, so it won't collect downvotes in the meantime

Comment: Do you want the *same* code iterate both the `struct link`-typed list and the `struct lstlst`-typed lists? (They are not "same struct" btw). This might be possible but is very probably much more trouble than it worth. Not a beginners' stuff in any case. I would recommend skipping it. Also, `typedef Link * List` is widely considered bad, don't do this, just use `Link*`.

Comment: yes .I know they arent thats why i set diffrent variables (i dont know what your way is going to be but the goal is to be similar to the first block of code on the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One function for `struct link` to print it recursively. Then we go up in the hierarchy, create a recursive function for printing `struct lstlst` which calls recursive function for printing `struct link`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct link_s {
    char value[20];
    struct link_s *next;
};

struct lstlst_s {
    struct link_s list;
    struct lstlst_s *next;
};

static void link_print(const struct link_s *elem) {
    printf("%s\n", elem->value);
}
static void link_print_recursively(const struct link_s *head) 
{
    if (head == NULL) return;
    link_print(head);
    link_print_recursively(head->next);
}
static void lstlst_print(const struct lstlst_s *elem) 
{
    link_print_recursively(&elem->list);
}
static void lstlst_print_recursively(const struct lstlst_s *head) {
    if (head == NULL) return;
    lstlst_print(head);
    lstlst_print_recursively(head->next);
}

// C11 _Generic can support both struct types
#define generic_print_recursively(head)  _Generic((head), \
        const struct lstlst_s *: lstlst_print_recursively, \
        const struct link_s *: link_print_recursively)(head)

int main()
{
    const struct lstlst_s lstlst_head = { 
        .list = { 
            .value = "1 1",
            .next = &(struct link_s){
                .value = "1 2",
                NULL,
            }
        },
        .next = &(struct lstlst_s){
            .list = { 
                "2 1",
                &(struct link_s){
                    "2 2",
                    NULL,
                }
            },
        }
    };
    const struct link_s link_head = {
        "3 1",
        &(struct link_s){
            .value = "3 2",
            NULL,
        }
    };

    printf("One\n");
    lstlst_print_recursively(&lstlst_head);
    link_print_recursively(&link_head);
    printf("Two\n");
    generic_print_recursively(&lstlst_head);
    generic_print_recursively(&link_head);

    return 0;
}
```

@edit: I have shortened the example structure and added a simple _Generic macro for function overloading on list/structure type.

Comment: Does this compile? And why the use of `static`

Comment: Yes, you can try it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/H1PrVtS-Q). You should always define symbols as statically visible, only declare them externally visible if you need. This is just one file, all symbols should be static.

Comment: I think that the use of `&(struct link_s)` is that you are hoping that undefined behaviour is in you favour.

Comment: so basicly impossible to gather them in one function?(judging from the complexity)

Comment: You want one function to handle `struct lstlst` and `struct link`? That would break some type-checking and some good practice, but why don't you use `_Generic` macro from C11 or some simple macro `#define print_recursively(listtype, head)  listtype##_print_recursively(head)`. You need to pass the type of the pointer somehow. C does not have function overload, like C++.

Comment: @EdHeal Taking an address of a [compound literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) is not an undefined behavior. Such practice is even used in example 3 in section 6.5.2.5 in [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: Please could you tell me if it does a `strcpy` into the array `value`?

Comment: If you ask if `struct link_s arr = {.value = "1 "1}` is equivalent to `struct link_s arr; strcpy(&arr.value, "1 1");`, then not really, it is equivalent to `struct link_s arr; memcpy(&arr.value, ((char[sizeof(arr.value)]){'1',' ','1',0x00,0x00,....,0x00}), sizeof(arr.value));`. What i mean is that the uninitialized bytes in arr.value will be set to 0x00, whereas when using strcpy the bytes after the string length will be left uninitialized. See [initiliazation from strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization).

Comment: Where in the spec that "1 1" changes into an array of characters that is 20 characters long.?

Comment: cppreference is just a simple reference (which sometimes is wrong), always check the C standard. It's from [C99, 6.7.8p21](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf). For example see [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780809/does-a-string-literal-count-as-a-partial-initializer-and-zero-initialize).

Comment: this seems pretty legit so ill take it.ill post again in a a few days hope to see you around.